# Excel 2010 error with Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: excel, tfs, excel-2010

When I try to create a new list for Team Foundation Server 2010 in Excel 2010 according to following printscreen:

[image]

I get following error, **although the .NET Programmibility Supoort for Excel 2010 is installed**.

[image]

I have already tried to register (regsvr32) the TFSOfficeAdd-in.dll in path: \Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies but it did not solve the problem!

Are there any ideas what could be the issue here?